# ggplot2 and purrr: loop with split() and refer to index value

Tags: r, ggplot2, purrr

I'm trying to loop many plots using ggplot2 and purrr::map() combined with split(). I can get the plots working fine, but I'm having trouble extracting the split value to use as a title.

Token data:

```
y=tibble(SplitVar=rep(c('A','B','C'),3),
         Variable=c(rep('A',3),rep('B',3),rep('C',3)),
         Value=runif(n=9))
```

The plots I want are generated by:

```
y%>%split(y$SplitVar)%>%map(~ggplot(.,aes(Variable,Value,fill=Variable))+
                             geom_col(position='dodge'))
```

[image: Sample Output Plot]

but I can't figure out how to get the SplitVar values 'A','B','C' extracted to be used as:

```
...+labs(title=...)
```

I can extract the values directly:

```
y%>%split(y$SplitVar)%>%names(.)
[1] "A" "B" "C"
```

but when I try to add this to the plots,

```
y%>%split(y$SplitVar)%>%map(~ggplot(.,aes(Variable,Value,fill=Variable))+
                            geom_col(position='dodge')+
                            labs(title=names(.)))
```

I get:
[image]
with the name of the variable, rather than the *values*.

**EDIT:**
My data values for A are actually nested for a second split value. I can now get the labels I need, but I can't get a map function to step into the nested loop for the first value and generate plots, then step back out for the other factors. A revised input is below:

```
y=tibble(Split1=c(rep('A',9),rep('B',3),rep('C',3)),
   Split2=c(rep(c('A','B','C'),3),rep('D',3),rep('E',3)),
   Var=c(rep('A',3),rep('B',3),rep('C',3),rep(c('A','B','C'),2)),
   Value=runif(15)
   )
```

I can split the tibble into the appropriate nested list with:

```
y%>%split(y$Split1)%>%map(~if(.$Split1=='A') split(.,.$Split2,drop=TRUE) else .)
```

But the best I can come up with is separately defining two procedures:

```
y[[1]]%>%map(~ggplot(.,aes(Variable,Value,fill=Variable))+
             geom_col(position='dodge')+
             labs(title=unique(.x$Split2)))

y2=y%>%filter(Split1!='A')
y2%>%split(y2$Split1,drop=TRUE)%>%map(~ggplot...)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
y %>%
   split(y$SplitVar) %>%
    map(~ggplot(.,aes(Variable,Value,fill=Variable))+
                        geom_col(position='dodge')+
                        labs(title=unique(.x$SplitVar)))
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you for the quick response. I'm unfamiliar with the .x and .y syntax so I'll do some reading and experimentation!

Comment: If you want to refer to the data itself in a `map` statement, use `.x`. You can also use `map2` such as @Aurele used, in which case the data is still `.x` and a second variable, `names(.)` is referred to by `.y`.

Comment: I worked through my application and found a complication: y$SplitVar[1] will actually have its own levels in SplitVar2, but it's the only one that is this way.

I've gotten code to make a list that is nested for 'A', but I can't find a clean method have map() step into the nested list only for 'A', then step back out and plot as usual for the rest of the examples.

I've spent the last 2 hours debugging, I'll update the sample data as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do:

```
y %>%
  split(y$SplitVar) %>%
  map2(
    names(.),
    ~ ggplot(.x,aes(Variable,Value,fill=Variable))+
      geom_col(position='dodge')+
      labs(title= .y))
```