# Get title for plots when using purrr and ggplot with group_by and nest()

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr

I have the following example:

```
df <- mtcars


plot <- df %>% 
  mutate(carb=as.character(carb)) %>% 
  group_by(carb) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
  mutate(plot=map(data, function(.x){ .x  %>%
      ggplot() +
      geom_bar(aes(mpg))
  }))

print(plot)

# A tibble: 6 x 3
  carb  data               plot    
  <chr> <list>             <list>  
1 4     <tibble [10 x 10]> <S3: gg>
2 1     <tibble [7 x 10]>  <S3: gg>
3 2     <tibble [10 x 10]> <S3: gg>
4 3     <tibble [3 x 10]>  <S3: gg>
5 6     <tibble [1 x 10]>  <S3: gg>
6 8     <tibble [1 x 10]>  <S3: gg>

for (i in 1:4){
  print(plots$plot[[i]])
}
```

Questions: 
1) How can I avoid the for loop and use a map function to print the plots?
2) How can I add a title for the plots.

Comment: where did you create `n`?  IN the current setup, it would be `imap` and `ggtitle` pass `.y`

Comment: Unless you need a column of `ggplot` objects in your data frame, it might be more straightforward to split the data by carb, then map over that list of data frames to make plots. Such as here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45107404/5325862

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to plot.

Comment: @akrun, camille. It is a copy-paste mistake. My own data set had a count which I calkes n. I an going to delete the question and update it when I am at a computer. Sorry!

Comment: If you edit the question. I want to plot something grouped by carb. And at a title. Like I said the n is just a numeric variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Making a data frame column of `ggplot` objects is a little unusual and cumbersome, but it can work if that's what suits the situation. (It seemed like `geom_bar` didn't actually make sense for this data, so I switched to histograms on a filtered subset of carbs).

With your method, you create the column of plots, save the data frame into a variable, then `map2` across the list-column of plots and the vector of `carb`s, adding a title to each plot. Then you can print any item from the resulting list, or print them all with `map` or `walk`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- mtcars %>%
  filter(carb %in% c(1, 2, 4)) %>%
  mutate(carb = as.character(carb))

df_with_plots <- df %>% 
  group_by(carb) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(plot = map(data, function(.x) { 
    .x  %>%
      ggplot() +
      geom_histogram(aes(mpg))
  }))

plots1 <- map2(df_with_plots$plot, df_with_plots$carb, ~(.x + labs(title = .y)))

# plots1[[1]] # would print out first plot in the list

walk(plots1, print)
```

[image]

*Removed additional plots for the sake of brevity*

The other option, which seems more straightforward, is to split the data frame into a list of data frames, then create plots however you need for each of those.

A few advantages: calling `split` gives each value of `carb` as the name of the corresponding list item, which you can access easily with `imap`, and which carries over to the `plots2` list (see below how I printed a plot by name). You can also do this in a single step. I also have a hard time working with nested data, because I'd prefer to be able to see the data frames, which you can do by printing out the split list of data frames.

```r
plots2 <- df %>%
  split(.$carb) %>%
  imap(function(carb_df, carb) {
    ggplot(carb_df) +
      geom_histogram(aes(mpg)) +
      labs(title = carb)
  })

plots2[["4"]]
```

[image]

As with the first method, you can print out all the plots with `walk(plots2, print)`.

Comment: @ camille, well it is not me... I only see one upvote which is myself.

Answer (score 7):

Your code to create you plots don't make very much sense but regardless this is how you would go about giving titles and plotting your graphics without using a for-loop:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  group_split(carb) %>% 
  imap(~ ggplot(data = .x) + 
        geom_bar(aes(mpg)) +
        labs(title = paste("Plot:", .y, "Carb:", unique(.x$carb))))
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

EDIT: I removed the plots just to not crowd the page. In this case `imap()` allows us to access the index as well as the value while we iterate. If you don't want to include the plot number in the title then `map()` will do just fine. Notice I also used `group_split()` which is in the newest release of `library(dplyr)`. Also, in your example you create a tibble of ggplots which is fine and dandy if you are doing more complex coding, but in the case of just creating plots the above method works just fine and is easier to understand. If you want to develop more complex plots you can extrapolate the `ggplot` out of the `map()` function and put it in its own function like so:

```
plot_carb <- function(df){
  ggplot(data = df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(mpg)) + 
  labs(title = paste(Carb: unique(.x$carb))) + 
  theme_bw()
}

mtcars %>%
group_split(carb) %>%
map(plot_carb)
```

Comment: @ thanks alot! Well I could only accept one answer and the other answer was first, but I have also learned new things from your answer.